# React Material-UI dropdown menu not working

Tags: drop-down-menu, reactjs, material-ui, iconmenu

I am creating a simple icon drop-down menu using Material UI. But after rendering the glyph appears and no `MenuItems` are shown after clicking on the it. Here is the code -

```
import { IconMenu, IconButton } from 'material-ui' ;
const MoreVertIcon = require('material-ui/lib/svg-icons/navigation/more-vert');
const MenuItem = require('material-ui/lib/menus/menu-item');

const PostCard = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        let button = (
                <IconButton
                    touch={true}
                    tooltip='Click to see menu.'
                    tooltipPosition='bottom-left'>
                    <MoreVertIcon />
                </IconButton>
            );
        return (
            <IconMenu iconButtonElement={button}>
                <MenuItem primaryText="Refresh" />
                <MenuItem primaryText="Send feedback" />
                <MenuItem primaryText="Settings" />
                <MenuItem primaryText="Help" />
                <MenuItem primaryText="Sign out" />
            </IconMenu>     
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Having exactly the same problem here...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I had a similar issue. Solution was to to add this somewhere in the app. I'm not sure if it matters where but I added it at a higher-level as possible:

```
var injectTapEventPlugin = require("react-tap-event-plugin");
injectTapEventPlugin();
```

Comment: just fyi. this has been fixed now with react v16+. no need to add these statements. Having these lines may actually slow down the click response to the user.

Answer (score 5):

Just wanted to add the reason to add injectTapEventPlugin.

According to [300ms tap delay, gone away By Jake Archibald](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/12/300ms-tap-delay-gone-away)

Browsers stopped waiting 300ms for double taps and react's onClick doesnt give us the proper handle.

and According to [react-tap-event-plugin git page](https://github.com/zilverline/react-tap-event-plugin)

> Facebook is not planning on supporting tap events (#436) because browsers are fixing/removing the click delay. Unfortunately it will take a lot of time before all mobile browsers (including iOS' UIWebView) will and can be updated.

Thats why we need to inject the plugin.
About the proper solution, I decided to add the package and inject it in the App's constructor (The higer level I have).

The import:

```
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';
```

And inside the constructor:

```
injectTapEventPlugin();
```

Comment: Best answer IMO

Comment: If you use React +16.4 you don't need to add the plugin. Just add in the package.json dependencies:`"react": "16.4.0", "react-dom": "16.4.0"`

Comment: after updating react to 16.13 i need deleted this plugin. but after it drop down menu not work.

Comment: @romanown can you please elaborate? This should have been resolved in React 16 and higher.

Comment: i have project where used var injectTapEventPlugin = require("react-tap-event-plugin");
injectTapEventPlugin(); after update the react from 15.4 to 16.13 i have error. in SO i find need delet this plugin. i deletit this. error is go out. buh drop down menu not have work. i only deleted this 2 string var injectTapEventPlugin = require("react-tap-event-plugin");
injectTapEventPlugin(); may be i need to edit my other the code? i to try v4 the material-ui

Comment: No, removing the `require` or `import` and the usage should fix your problem. What's the error you're getting now?

Comment: @Matan Bobi Sorry I didn't see your message. there is no error. the drop-down menu doesn't work. i can see clicking on the item but the items do not appear.

Comment: @romanown sounds to me like you should open a new issue for this and elaborate on what's happening and what you see.. I don't think it's related to this issue, sorry.

Comment: I'm using react ^16.4.0 and the menu doesn't work, so all the comments stating things along the lines of "not needed with 6.14" are not clear at all

Answer (score 1):

In my case I have to add injectTapEventPlugin as well as change handler.

```
var injectTapEventPlugin = require("react-tap-event-plugin");
const DropDownMenu = require('material-ui/lib/drop-down-menu');

...

injectTapEventPlugin(); // in constructor 

...

  handleChange(event, selectedIndex, menuItem) {
    this.setState({menu: event.target.value });
  }

...
  // in render
  let menuItems = [
       { payload: '0', text: 'Mon - Sun' },
       { payload: '1', text: 'Mon - Sat' },
       { payload: '2', text: 'Mon - Fri' },
       { payload: '3', text: 'Mon - Fri / Mon - Thu' },
    ];
...
  // in render return

  <DropDownMenu menuItems={menuItems} selectedIndex={this.state.menu} onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

Comment: how to do this if we have 2 dropdown with same content?